# Mongodb schema design advice

Tags: mongodb, database-schema

I am working on my first mongodb project and am trying to wrap my head around schema design in Mongodb vs relational dbs.

I want to create a databases of vegetables from several rss feeds. Each of these feeds has a tag for vegetable name for me to use.

1) I get 2  feeds for vegetable nutritional information

2) 3 feeds for vegetable growing/farming information

3) 4 feeds for blog articles

There are only 500 different vegetables i get information for.

Would the best schema in this scenario be:

A)  to have one collection for each vegetable and have sub collection for nutrition, growing and blog articles?

B) Or to have one collection for nutritional information, one for farming information and one for blog articles?

I envision the users primarily querying on vegetable name, but it will be possible to query on other fields as well.

Comment: Is the nutritional information for a veggie some kind of static information (e.g. "lettuce has 20kcal per kg"), or is it aggregated from multiple sources (e.g. there's twelve sets of nutritional information from different sources for this veggie)? Same question for growing information. If it is static, I'd agree with Calvin. If not, I'd go for option B.

Comment: Hi it is aggregated from several sources.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is schemaless - so you don't have to think about this in the same way as you would a relational database.  I know it's confusing at first.  Also, MongoDB does not support "Sub-collections" - you have documents (individual entities) within a collection.

I would actually opt for this:

C) Two collections.  The veggies collection is essentially a complex array structure containing not only the information about the veggies, but also the growing / nutrition info.  Just make sure you [create an index](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes) for each piece you will need to search on.  A separate collection for blog posts if you can't use a blogging engine that already exists.

That's the beauty of NoSQL - as long as you index - you can make each entity (called a document in Mongo's case) pretty complex.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Take care with MongoDB indexes: it can use **only one index per query**: an index for each field separately won't help that much if it only reduces the result set marginally.